# Understand range of value in RISCV register

Tags: riscv

Is it correct that, a RISC-V register value's MSB is used as signed bit to differentiate between negative and positive number and negatives are stored as 2's complement with sign extension if required.
So range for a value in risc-v register is -2^31 to (2^31 - 1) ?

Tried an simulator at https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2019sp/riscv/interpreter/#

Answer (score 2):

The registers are just raw storage of 32 bits wide on RV32 (64 bits on RV64) and without an inherent associated numeric interpretation, which is one reason debuggers and such often show numbers in hex (or binary).

Here are some possible interpretations:

- 2's complement signed number having the range you mention, -2<sup>31</sup> .. 2<sup>31</sup>-1
- Unsigned number having range 0 .. 2<sup>32</sup>-1
- Pointer/address (i.e. unsigned)
- 1's complement signed having range of -2<sup>31</sup>-1 .. 2<sup>31</sup>-1
- Sign-magnitude (of same range as above)
- Character (one or up to 4 ascii characters)
- Enum
- Low half of 64-bit value
- High half of 64-bit value
- IEEE 754 single precision floating point
- Low half of IEEE 754 double precision floating point
- High half of IEEE 754 double precision floating point
- Unknown raw storage (e.g. when used to copy memory)
- Boolean value

You see, the registers are just raw storage — it is up to the program to give meaning to the storage by the way it chooses to interpret and use the registers and memory.  The machine code program chooses interpretation by using machine code instructions that treat as signed, treat as unsigned, or shift, mask rotate, etc..

CPU registers (and memory) are frequently repurposed, for a while one register may be treated as signed, then shortly after treated as unsigned — they're just raw storage.

High level languages have logical variables, which are assigned data types.  Logical variables have lifetimes, such as those for a procedure/function — they come into existence on function invocation, and go out of existence on function return.

The machine code environment, by contrast, simply has physical storage of CPU registers and memory.  Physical storage is (more or less) permanent, and globally accessible to all code in the program.

To execute a high level language program, those logical variables are mapped to some physical storage and consistently treated (with appropriate size and sign'ness) as long as that logical variable exists.  When the logical variable's lifetime ends (e.g. a procedure/function exits) the physical storage for that logical variable can be repurposed for another logical variable.

Even within a single function, machine code program needs temporary variables for a variety of reasons (e.g. expression evaluation), and is often repurposing the CPU registers for different temporary variables.

So, looking at a frozen machine code program's CPU registers alone, we don't really know how they are being used and what kind of value they hold, without also following along with the program.

Comment: how to implement a SUB instruction in RISCV VM ?
should I check if both values RS1 and RS2 are negative and based on that perform the operation and again store the result as 2'complement ?

Comment: We use 2's complement signed form because the bit pattern for their results is the same as for unsigned.  So, just subtract the two numbers as if they were both unsigned.  Or subtract as if they were both signed.  Or negate the 2nd argument (2's complement negation) and use addition.  It won't matter, you'll get the same bit pattern result.  The result is just a bit pattern, it is for the machine code program (not the processor) to decide if it wants to see those bits as signed or unsigned.